# Why is MySQL returning different counts for a query when I add in another element to a set - using FIND_IN_SET, GROUP BY, and COUNT(*)

Tags: mysql, group-by, find-in-set

I have a MySQL query to get a summary of devices and their locations:

```
SELECT `devicetypes`.`permanentslug`,
   `devices`.`yearmanufactured`,
   `engagements`.`name` AS `location`,
   Count(*) AS `count`
FROM `devices`
   INNER JOIN `devicemodels`
           ON `devicemodels`.`id` = `devices`.`devicemodelid`
   INNER JOIN `devicetypes`
           ON `devicetypes`.`id` = `devicemodels`.`devicetypeid`
   INNER JOIN `locations`
           ON `locations`.`id` = `devices`.`locationid`
   INNER JOIN `engagements`
           ON `engagements`.`id` = `locations`.`engagementid`
WHERE  `devices`.`deletedat` IS NULL
   AND `devicemodels`.`deletedat` IS NULL
   AND `devicetypes`.`deletedat` IS NULL
   AND `locations`.`deletedat` IS NULL
   AND `engagements`.`deletedat` IS NULL
   AND Find_in_set(`locations`.`engagementid`, '224,286') > 0
GROUP  BY `devicetypes`.`permanentslug`,
      `locations`.`name`,
      `devices`.`yearmanufactured`
ORDER  BY `devicetypes`.`permanentslug` ASC,
      `engagements`.`name` ASC;
```

When I run this, I get the following results:

| permanentslug | yearManufactured | location | count |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| defibs | null | clinics | 1 |
| defibs | null | clinics | 1 |
| defibs | 2012 | clinics | 1 |
| defibs | 2020 | Hospital | 2 |
| defibs | null | Hospital | 1 |

Which is kind of accurate, however it's odd that it isn't combining the top two lines and giving me a count of 2 for that row. But then, when I add another element into the array I'm checking with FIND_IN_SET, I get inaccurate results. Here's the new query that only adds 223 to the Find_in_set line:

```
SELECT `devicetypes`.`permanentslug`,
   `devices`.`yearmanufactured`,
   `engagements`.`name` AS `location`,
   Count(*) AS `count`
FROM `devices`
   INNER JOIN `devicemodels`
           ON `devicemodels`.`id` = `devices`.`devicemodelid`
   INNER JOIN `devicetypes`
           ON `devicetypes`.`id` = `devicemodels`.`devicetypeid`
   INNER JOIN `locations`
           ON `locations`.`id` = `devices`.`locationid`
   INNER JOIN `engagements`
           ON `engagements`.`id` = `locations`.`engagementid`
WHERE  `devices`.`deletedat` IS NULL
   AND `devicemodels`.`deletedat` IS NULL
   AND `devicetypes`.`deletedat` IS NULL
   AND `locations`.`deletedat` IS NULL
   AND `engagements`.`deletedat` IS NULL
   AND Find_in_set(`locations`.`engagementid`, '223,224,286') > 0
GROUP  BY `devicetypes`.`permanentslug`,
      `locations`.`name`,
      `devices`.`yearmanufactured`
ORDER  BY `devicetypes`.`permanentslug` ASC,
      `engagements`.`name` ASC;
```

And the results yield:

| permanentslug | yearManufactured | location | count |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| defibs | null | clinics | 1 |
| defibs | 2012 | clinics | 1 |
| defibs | 2020 | Hospital | 2 |
| defibs | null | Hospital | 1 |
| defibs | 2015 | Creekside | 7 |
| defibs | 2019 | Creekside | 4 |
| defibs | null | Creekside | 9 |

So, now it's completely removing one of the null clinics rows, but it's not combining it's count together with the other row. Very strange overall. Is this maybe an issue with FIND_IN_SET ? I've never seen MySQL miscount like this before.

Comment: Please provide sample data that produces this result.

Comment: Sometimes an index can get corrupted and produce errors like this.

Comment: Do you have the same problem with `locations.engagementid IN (223,224,286)`?

Comment: Hey @Barmar - Thanks for the insight. It did have a similar issue for `locations.engagementid IN (223,224,286)` but even more different numbers which really had me confused. I did figure it out - the issue was in my GROUP BY. Outlined the solution below.

Answer (score 0):

I knew this had to be some silly mistake in my SQL query and sure enough it was. The GROUP BY at the bottom of the query is grouping by `locations.name` however I'm then displaying `engagements.name AS location` in my results.

When I changed the GROUP BY to be

`GROUP BY DeviceTypes.permanentslug, Engagements.name, Devices.yearManufactured`

it fixed everything. Hopefully nobody spent the time reading all of this before I figured it out.